# PHP Autoload Catching new Exception

Tags: php, exception, autoload

I have the following code defined to automatically include my classes:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
   require $class . '.php';
});
```

I then have a third party class (within the helpers namespace) with the following line:

```
throw new Exception('...');
```

The problem is that the autoload function tried to look for a file called helpers\Exception.php. I therefore changed my function above to:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if ($class != 'helpers\Exception') {
        require $class . '.php';
    }
}
```

But then it throws an exception saying the class helpers\Exception was not found. I'd appreciate it if someone could help show me how I can get it to simply display the original exception thrown in the third party class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this working. I had to add the following to the top of the class:

```
use Exception;
```

Another solution is to change:

```
throw new Exception('...');
```

to:

```
throw new \Exception('...');
```

But this solution requires changing every occurrence throughout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` character. Try this: `helpers\\Exception`

Comment: Thanks but that made no difference. The issue that it is trying to look for an Exception class which does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure the class is included? If it isn't, you should include it :)

Comment: problem solved. Please see my answer for the solution. Thanks anyway.